# The number of custom close reasons

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation, custom-close-reasons

It is hard to fit all the common off-topic close reasons we use into 3 large categories. If our goal is to give the best feedback to the authors when putting their questions on hold, why are we restricting the number of custom close reasons to just 3? Shouldn't we have a bit larger number of custom close reasons (e.g. 7) if they are commonly used?

One more thing, I noticed that the size of custom close reasons is 400 characters while the size of comments is 600. It would be nice if the size of custom close reasons is increased to 600 characters so we can keep using what we were posting as comments when closing questions as off-topic in the custom close reason's box.

Comment: duplicate of the first half (on Ask Ubuntu Meta): [Can we have more than 3 custom close reasons, pretty please?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6994/can-we-have-more-than-3-custom-close-reasons-pretty-please)

Comment: Thanks @Jan for the link.

Comment: I think you should edit out your second paragraph into a separate question.  I think there is a much better case for the first request than the second, and you may be missing out on upvotes by asking two questions in one.

Comment: A question related to your first suggestion (though it's closed as a duplicate of a question unrelated to the number of custom close reasons): [Could we make the amount of close reasons not a fixed quantity for the SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279486/335251)